# I am trying to figure out a way to convert month name to integer

Tags: c, string, date, multidimensional-array, token

So basically I need to find a way to make the month of my date Convert to number as well as my time to go from military time to standard time.
I am getting issues running my code and can't figure out why. It's probably a simple mistake but if you guys figure out please let me know.

```
from Monday, June 2, 2012, 22:12:12 to 6/2/2012, 10:12 PM format.
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/*This code will take user input of date and use 2-d array to store strings
 using delimeter as well. It will list all
 the date in descending order seperating:
   "Month", "Day", "Year", "Hour", "Minute", "Second"
   from:
   "Saturday, July 8, 2017, 22:14:10"
*/

int findMonthNum(const char *key);

int main(void){


    char *check[] = {
            "Saturday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday",
            "Sunday", "Friday",
#if 1
            NULL
#endif
    };

    char *monthString[] = {
            "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
            "October", "November", "December",
#if 1
            NULL
#endif
    };

    char **day;
    char **month;


    // creates 2 day array
    char date[8][20];

    // creates order of time
    char *order[] = { "Month", "Day", "Year", "Hour", "Minute", "Second" };

    printf("Enter date separated by commas in following format:\n");
    printf(" Example: Saturday, July 8, 2017, 22:14:10\n");

    // array to store string initially
    char text[64];

    // reads strings
    fgets(text, 64, stdin);

    // this is the delimeter that will be helpful for seperating it to
    // different tokens
    char *delims = " ,:";
    char *token = strtok(text, delims);
    char **label = order;
    int r = 0;

    while (token) {
        // look for match on day of the week
        for (day = check;  *day != NULL;  ++day) {
            if (strcmp(token,*day) == 0)
                break;
        }

        // if _not_ day of the week, store the value
        if (*day == NULL) {
            strcpy(date[r], token);

            printf("%-8s: %s\n ", *label, date[r]);

            label++;
            r++;
        }

        // this is so that it will find null values at the end and leave off
        // where it was.
        token = strtok(NULL, delims);


    }
    // Convert the above date to 7/8/2017, 10:14 PM format
     int findMonthNum(const char *key){
        static const char *monthStrings[] = {
                "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
                "October", "November", "December", NULL
        };

        for( int i = 0; monthStrings[i] != NULL; i++ ) {
            if( strcmp(monthStrings[i], key) == 0 ) {
                return i+1;
            }
        }

        return -1;

    }


        printf("%d/%s/%s, %s:%s", findMonthNum(date[0]), date[1], date[2], date[4], date[5]);




    return 0;
}
```

It keeps saying expected expression before consts.

Comment: You did the searching for the day of week. The month is right after the day of week. Therefore, you should do like that after the day conversion.

Comment: #if 1
            NULL
#endif              I am wondering what this does because I use it in my code because someone suggested it to me but I dont know what its for exactly and if I should use it again for the monthstring @MikeCAT

Comment: The `NULL` is for stopping searching for in case invalid string is passed. therefore, `NULL` is required but `#if 1` and `#endif` can be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through `monthString` until you match, then return the index + 1, or -1 if it isn't found.

```
int findMonthNum(const char *key) {
    // This is declared `static` so it's only ever allocated once.
    //
    // It's declared inside the function so long as the function is
    // the only thing using it.
    //
    // It's declared `const char *monthStrings[]` because
    // it is an array of `const char *`. "Strings like this" are
    // constants and cannot be modified.
    //
    // The NULL at the end lets us known when to stop iterating
    // without knowing the length of the array.
    static const char *monthStrings[] = {
        "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
        "October", "November", "December", NULL
    };

    // Iterate from monthStrings[0] until you hit a NULL value.
    for( int i = 0; monthStrings[i] != NULL; i++ ) {
        if( strcmp(monthStrings[i], key) == 0 ) {
            return i+1;
        }
    }

    // Return -1 if you don't find a matching month.
    return -1;
}

int monthNum = findMonthNum("June"); // 6
monthNum = findMonthNum("Septembuary"); // -1
```

However, C has built in functions [`strptime`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strptime) to parse datetimes and [`strftime`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime) to format them. They both use the same sprintf-like specification to parse and format.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    char date[] = "Monday, June 2, 2012, 22:12:12";
    struct tm parsed;

    // Parse the string into a struct tm.
    strptime(date, "%A, %B %e, %Y, %T", &parsed);

    // Print it to check it parsed correctly.
    printf("parsed: %s\n", asctime(&parsed));

    // Format the struct tm to a new string.
    char formatted[40];
    strftime(
        formatted,
        sizeof(formatted), 
        "%D %I:%M %p",
        &parsed
    );
    printf("formatted: %s\n", formatted);
}
```

Comment: i'm not sure what to do with key since in my code i've never used it before @Schwern

Comment: @user3117455 `key` holds the parameter passed into `findMonthNum`. That is `"June"` in `findMonthNum("June")`. You'd pass in `date[1]`... I think it's `date[1]`; a struct would work better than an array to store the parsed date as P__J__ suggests. You're reimplementing `struct tm`.

Comment: @user3117455 Don't put functions inside other functions. It "works" but it's a mess. Put it before `main` where you have your forward declaration. Then you don't need a forward declaration. It's also bad practice to edit an answer into your question, future people will be confused. If you're having trouble with an answer, use something like [gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/) to show your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have it without any stdlib functions .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct
{
    int year, month, day;
    int hour, min, sec;
    int am;
}mytime_t;

unsigned mystrtou(const char *str)
{
    unsigned result = 0;
    while(*str)
    {
        result *= 10;
        result += *str++ - '0';
    }
    return result;
}

char *skipspaces(char *str)
{
    while(*str && (*str == ' ' || *str == ',')) str++;
    return str;
}

int streq(const char *str1, const char *str2)
{
    int result = 0;
    while(*str1 || *str2)
    {
        if(*str1++ != *str2++)
        {
            result = 1;
            break;
        }

    }
    return result;
}

int slice(char *mil, char **argv)
{
    int argc = 0;

    mil = skipspaces(mil);
    if(*mil)
    {
        argc++;
        *argv = mil;
        argv++;
    }
    while(*mil)
    {
        if(*mil == ',' || *mil == ' ' || *mil == ':')
        {
            *mil++ = 0;
            mil = skipspaces(mil);
            if(*mil)
            {
                argc++;
                *argv = mil;
                argv++;
            }
        }
        mil++;
    }
    return argc;
}

const char *monthNames[] = {
        "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
        "October", "November", "December",
};

int getMonth(const char *month)
{
    int result = -1;
    for(int index = 0; index < sizeof(monthNames) / sizeof(monthNames[0]); index++)
    {
        if(!streq(month, monthNames[index]))
        {
            result = index + 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int convert(char *data, mytime_t *time)
{
    int result = -1;
    char *argv[10];
    int argc = slice(data, argv);

    if(argc == 7)
    {
        result = 0;
        time -> am = 1;
        time -> year = mystrtou(argv[3]);
        time -> month = getMonth(argv[1]);
        time -> day = mystrtou(argv[2]);

        time -> hour = mystrtou(argv[4]);
        time -> min = mystrtou(argv[5]);
        time -> sec = mystrtou(argv[6]);
        if(time -> hour > 12)
        {
            time -> am = 0;
            time -> hour -= 12; 
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    char str[] = "Monday, June 2, 2012, 22:12:12";

    mytime_t time;

    convert(str, &time);
    

    printf("%d/%d/%d %d:%d %s\n", time.month, time.day, time.year, time.hour, time.min,  time.am ? "am" : "pm");
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/qSFh8p

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative to checking the name up to 12 times**

In mapping a month name to an index, we can have some hash fun.

Let us assume month names remain as there are in English.
Notice that the 2nd & 3rd characters are enough to distinguish all 12.

Hash by adding those 2 characters and look at the 5 LSbits to form an index into a map.
Compare if the mapped value matches.
Very fast - only 1 string compare.

Of course this is not directly applicable if code used a different set on month names.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

static const char *monthString[] = { //
    "January", "February", "March", "April", //
    "May", "June", "July", "August", //
    "September", "October", "November", "December" };

int month_to_index(const char *month_name) {
  size_t len = strlen(month_name);
  if (len >= 3) {
    unsigned sum = (tolower(month_name[1]) + tolower(month_name[2])) %32;
    static const unsigned char table[32] = {
        [1] = 7, [2] = 4, [3] = 6, [5] = 11, //
        [7] = 2, [8] = 12, [15] = 1, [19] = 3, //
        [21] = 9, [23] = 10, [26] = 5, [28] = 8 //
    };
    unsigned index = table[sum];
    if (index && strncasecmp(month_name, monthString[index-1], len) == 0) {
      return index;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Sample use

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  for (int mm = 0; mm<12; mm++) {
    char buf[20];
    strcpy(buf, monthString[mm]);
    int len = strlen(buf);
    if (len > 3) {
      int offset = rand() % (len-3) + 3;
      buf[offset] = '\0';
    }
    for (int i=0; buf[i]; i++) {
      if (rand()%2) {
        buf[i] ^= 'A' ^ 'a'; // toggle case
      }
    }
    unsigned index = month_to_index(monthString[mm]);
    if (index > 0) {
      printf("%2i %2u <%10s> <%s>\n", mm, index, monthString[mm], buf);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
 0  1 <   January> <jaNu>
 1  2 <  February> <FebRUA>
 2  3 <     March> <maRc>
 3  4 <     April> <apR>
 4  5 <       May> <may>
 5  6 <      June> <jUn>
 6  7 <      July> <jUL>
 7  8 <    August> <AUgu>
 8  9 < September> <SePTe>
 9 10 <   October> <OCT>
10 11 <  November> <nOvem>
11 12 <  December> <deC>
```